# Specific image from Rails 4.2 image cache will not update, no matter what we try

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

We are using Rails 4.2.x running in development. We have a logo image in our header partial (app/views/layouts/_header1.html.erb). A modification was made to the logo image, and the updated image was uploaded to the server (to app/assets/images) with the same filename as the original image (original image was overwritten). The image is listed with a link_to tag in _header1.html.erb:

```
<div id="header1_left">
    <div id="logo">
        <%= link_to(image_tag("ourlogo.svg"), root_path) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

We are using Passenger 5 on CentOS 6. When we view the page in a browser, for a split second, you see a checksum value appear in the place of this image, then the image appears. We have tried updating _header1.html.erb with arbitrary values to confirm we do see updates to that partial in our browser. No matter what we try, Rails is still serving the legacy image. We have tried the following:

- rake assets:clean
- rake assets:clobber
- rails c, then Rails.cache.clear
- manually rm -rfing /tmp/cache/assets/development
- uploading the image to app/assets/images with a different filename, then updating _header1.html.erb to use the new filename
- adding :"data-no-turbolink" => true to the end of the link_to call that contains the image_tag
- clearing the cache fully on all browsers, perma-disabling cache in Firefox via Firebug, accessing the site from new machines that have not accessed the site at all
- restarting httpd multiple times
- restarting the CentOS server entirely
- inspecting the image element using Firebug and searching the dev server filesystem for any files matching the provided checksum-based filename or a segment of that filename, using find / -iname "*part_of_filename*", updatedb / locate, etc
- migrating the site entirely to a new server (rsyncing -arvP all data from that Rails' app's directory to another CentOS 6 host using passenger, same issue appears on new host)
- confirmed the following are set in config/environments/development.rb:

  ```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.cache_store = [:null_store]

  config.cache_classes = false
  ```

Does anyone have any earthly idea what the problem could be? The filename is correct, we've repeatedly confirmed the file app/assets/images/ourlogo.svg is the correct file. Where else could this be cached? Could it be turbolinks? Could it be passenger? Could it even be apache?

Comment: Does a copy of the image exist in the `public/assets` directory?

Comment: Thank you for the response. No, I just reviewed all images in app/assets/images and all of them are the current version of the logo. We have no public/assets directory on this Rails 4.2 development site. All that exists within /public is 404.html, 422.html, 500.html, favicon.ico, and robots.txt. No subdirectories. The site is still loading the legacy version of the logo which exists nowhere within app/assets/images or public.

Comment: Note: I created public/assets and copied the known-good image there, cycled httpd, rake assets:clobber, still no effect on multiple clean browsers.

Comment: If you use a new image with a different file name and use that new file name in the partial it is not a asset caching issue.  Perhaps try this again and place other new content right next to the image to make sure the partial changes is taking effect.  I know you have tried this but it is simply impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At long last, we have resolved the issue. It did in fact turn out not to be a Rails caching issue, but a problem with the image itself (apparently) being affected by the font settings of the various machines. Our designer converted the image to vector format and now all is working properly. Thank you all very much for the assistance and feedback. Hopefully the various steps listed in this post can help future Rails 4.2 developers with cache clearing issues, as we exhausted several potential avenues in an effort to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and `rake assets:clean` did the trick.